# Python Language Server Protocol with virtual environment

Tags: neovim, filetype-python, plugin-ale

Can anyone help me get things like "Go to definition" working with Neovim and Python virtual environments?

My setup currently uses a specific virtual environment for Neovim (as recommended by `:checkhealth`) which is working fine.

I've installed `python-language-server` and `pyls-mypy` into that virtual environment.

In my `.vimrc` I've got `w0rp/ale` installed with the following configuration:

```
let g:ale_linters = {
      \ 'python': ['flake8', 'pyls']
      \}
let g:ale_virtualenv_dir_names = ['.venv']
```

I'm now in a directory with a virtual environment in `./.venv` (which isn't activated) and can't get any LSP stuff like `:ALEGoToDefinition` to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this by installed `python-language-server` globally like this:

```
sudo -H pip install python-language-server
```

I don't know how popular a solution this will be, but it works for me, so I'm happy.

Since the ale documentation for `ALEGoToDefinition` says

```
Jump to the definition of a symbol under the cursor using the enabled LSP
linters for the buffer. ALE will jump to a definition if an LSP server
provides a location to jump to. Otherwise, ALE will do nothing.
```

the language server is probably necessary.

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider accepting the answer!